# Count in query ruin expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

### Database structure

[image: Database structure]

### Data

[image: data]

### Without count in query:

```
SELECT id, a FROM test ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1
```

Good result: [image: without count]

### With count in query:

```
SELECT id, a, COUNT(*) FROM test ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1
```

Bad result: [image: with count]

Why is this happening? What is alternative?

Comment: Why do you think the result is bad?

Comment: Not sure why this would be happening to you, an explain plan might shed some light on it. Out of curiosity, try running with COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(*).

Comment: @Fls'Zen COUNT(1) works same as *. Explain gives me 'Using filesort' in Extra row for query without count, and empty string in Extra row for query with count. Is there way to enable filesort for query with count?

Comment: You should explain your goal in your question. Your query is not very meaningfull. Remove `LIMIT 1` and see what happens.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel after remove `LIMIT 1` count shows same result as before, without count shows all 5 rows.

Comment: [MySQL docs function_found-rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT id, a, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) as cnt 
FROM test
ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1
```

It should give the expected results. Even though I'm pretty sure the optimizer will execute subquery only once, it always makes sense to check execution plan with `EXPLAIN` .

Comment: This is work, but what if i need to query like that: SELECT id, a, COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE a != 0 AND id != 5 ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1. Then i need to add same where to subquery too.

Comment: Yes , you need to repeat the condition in both places.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select any other attribute in sql when you are using an aggregate function on the query unless and until the other attribute is used in 'GROUP BY' clause. So a way around it could be

```
SELECT id,a,t.cnt
FROM (SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM test) as t, test
ORDER BY a LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The DBMS is doing something as follows and because the aggregation for `id` and `a` are missing it chooses any value it wants to.

```
SELECT id, a, COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS dummy, id, a FROM test
) t
GROUP BY dummy
ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1
```

In other DBMS you could use `WITH`, so you don't have to rewrite the where clause (in MySQL you could only create a view to simulate this). See @a1ex07's answer for the correct query.